# Map blanking after setting changing property value

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm running into this really weird issue I have no idea how to debug.
I am making changes in the studio environment. Map looks good there:

[image]

After saving and downloading the new style.json, i add it to my project but then the map stops working. It just blanks. No console errors, no nothing.

The only difference in style.json and what seems to be breaking the map is this snippet :

```
    "text-translate": [
    "interpolate",
    [
        "linear"
    ],
    [
        "zoom"
    ],
    5,
    [
        "literal",
        [
            0,
            0
        ]
    ],
    8,
    [
        "literal",
        [
            120,
            20
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is it possible that I need to upgrade my version of mapbox gl js or something like that?

Comment: You haven't really given enough information to solve the problem. Can you provide a live demo? In any case, yes it's totally possible that upgrading to the latest mapbox-gl-js would solve it.

Comment: thanks @SteveBennett it was in fact an issue with the mapbox-gl-js version. I was using "interpolate" which needs >= 0.42.0 (i was using 0.41.0)